# PowerShell :: input a list as param

Tags: list, powershell, parameters, scripting, parameter-passing

In the same directory I have 2 files:

- `Servers.txt` (which contains a list of server names)
- `test.ps1` (which is my PowerShell script)

my test.ps1 contains this code:

```
param(
    $Servers = get-content -Path "Servers.txt"
    ForEach($Server in $Servers) {
        $instance = $Server}
)
```

As soon as I try to run it I incur in the error:

```
At C:\test.ps1:2 char:15
+     $Servers = get-content -Path "Servers.txt"
+               ~
Missing expression after '='.
At C:\test.ps1:2 char:13
+     $Servers = get-content -Path "Servers.txt"
+             ~
Missing ')' in function parameter list.
At C:\test.ps1:5 char:1
+ )
+ ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken
```

Which is very odd as the code is so simple.

The goal is to input a list of server names that I'm later going to parse.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use output from a *command* (as opposed to an *expression*) as a parameter variable's default value, you must convert it to an expression with `(...)`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--):

```
# Parameter declarations
param(
    $Servers = (get-content -Path "Servers.txt")
)

# Function body.
ForEach($server in $Servers) {
  $instance = $server
}
```

Note: Use of `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), is only required if the default value must be determined via *multiple* commands (or whole *statement*(s), such as `foreach` or `while` loop).